# Sql server : removing database name prefix

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to remove the database name as the prefix of a table within a query.

The following query works:

```
select USER_ID, NAME, STATUS from CSBK.dbo.T_USERS;
```

But I would like to know how to get this one to work without the database name:

```
select USER_ID, NAME, STATUS from dbo.T_USERS;
```

Otherwise I'm getting the following error

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name
```

**UPDATE**

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://SOMETHING.COM:1438", "CSBK", "aPassword");
```

ideally i would like to use only the table name without any prefix but it seems the scheme name is required by sql server.

Comment: You're using this in Java code, right? Could you share your connectionstring in that case?

Comment: you run this query in a program or in dbms ?

Comment: Have you tried remove `dbo.` as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx)

> Connect to a named database on a remote server:
>   jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=AdventureWorks

which will be in your case:

`jdbc:sqlserver://SOMETHING.COM:1438;databaseName=CSBK`